# Multiplying matrices in c

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply 2 matrices A and B and then store the result in c. The matrices are stored inside 1 dimensional arrays.Can anyone tell me please whats wrong with my code, why cant I print the result that I get from multiplying matrix a and b.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int m, i, j, k, n, x;
    double *A, *B, *C, sum;

    //allocating dynamic memory
    A= (double*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
    B= (double*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
    C= (double*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));

    //initializing matrices with values
    for(i =0; i< m*n; i++){
        A[i] = 1.;
        B[i] = 2.;

    }
    //Multiplying the matrices
    for(i=0; i<m; i++ ){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
             sum =0;
             for(k=0; k<n; k++){
                 sum+= A[i*n +k]* B[k*n +j];
                 C[i*n +j] = sum;
                 printf("matrix result %f\n", C[i*n +j]); 
             }
        }
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: where `m` and `n` are initialized? You are using variables that are not initialized.

Comment: Seeing as how none of those variables are initialized before you use them in your `malloc` call, this program is going to explode. **Always** initialize variables before using them. You should also declare your variables closer to where you're using them, or give them longer, more meaningful names. This code is like a riddle.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I was sure that I initialized the variables at the top and I am not getting any compilation errors.

Comment: In addition to this you are printing C to early. Finish the multiplication loop and then start a new output loop. Lastly: Never implement linear algebar yourself use Lapack!

Comment: @n1e2 as PaulRoub said, please stop vandalizing your question. By removing the code you invalidate all the answers. What is it you are trying to achieve with this? What is your goal? Why do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize any variable before use it, so in your code, you need to initialize `m` and `n` to 2 since this is 2D matrix.

Comment: The structure of their code is what makes the matrices 2D, not the values of `m` or `n`. `m` and `n` can take on any value as long as they're equal to each other.

Comment: @frslm, tomayto tomahto.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your variables `n` and `m` are not initialized.
2. You are not freed allocated memory.
3. Use 1D array as 2D is good idea.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi thank you for your feedback, I was sure that I initialized the variables at the top, and I am not getting any compilation errors is just that I am not getting an output. Thanks

Comment: By default compiler hardly did not tell you about doubtful code expressions. To make compiler stronger you may pass some options. For example if you using GCC, pass them `--pedantic` and `-Wall` options.